# Symfony setup without a web folder

Tags: php, symfony1, shared-hosting

I need to setup Symfony on a shared host that runs on windows IIS. The domain directs to the root folder of the host. Which means no /public_html or /htdocs.

Is there any way to configure Symfony in a way that if I move the contents in "/web" to the root folder of my shared hosting account with the rest of the folders (app, config, tests etc...) , it would still work ?

Comment: Please refer to [symfony on IIS](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/symfonyOnIIS)

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can do this.

Just do:

**Open** - `lib\symfony\config\sfProjectConfiguration.class.php`
**Find** -  `$this->setWebDir($rootDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'web');` function
**Modify** - "web" folder by whatever path or directory you want

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can do symbolic links to a directory. The windows equivalent of a symlink to the root directory named web would solve your problem I guess...

Answer (score 0):

## Symfony on IIS

In the first case, the webserver is only used for our symfony project, and the URL is something like http://myproject/.

Assuming the directory in which you created the directory myapp is c:\myproject\, configure the root directory of your server to be c:\myproject\web (in IIS administration console).